# Why does this XAML behave differently? Elements leaving app window UWP

Tags: xaml, uwp

I have an app with a dropdownbutton flyout. I'm migrating the XAML over to a new project and the dropdownbutton is behaving differently. In the first instance, the dropdown flyout would be alligned to the left edge of the button (what I want it to do). In the second instance, it is aligned to the right edge of the button and contained within the apps window.

## XAML

```
    <DropDownButton ToolTipService.ToolTip="File"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="Transparent"
                    Style="{StaticResource CommandBarFlyoutEllipsisButtonStyle}"
                    Height="33"
                    FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE700;">

        <DropDownButton.Flyout>
            <MenuBarItemFlyout Placement="LeftEdgeAlignedTop">

                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Open File" Icon="OpenFile" Tag="Open File"
                        Click="OpenLocalFile"/>

            </MenuBarItemFlyout>
        </DropDownButton.Flyout>

    </DropDownButton>
```

## First app (how I want it to look)

[image]

## Second app

[image]

There are a number of differences between the two apps but the xaml is almost identical. I can't seem to pinpoint what could cause this fly out to behave differently. Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: Those differences are seen on same PC? I remember that menu displays on different side when user has chosen mouse for right or left hand.

Comment: I'd look into that but fairly certain it isn't that since screen shots are from the same computer with both apps open at the same time. My speculation is that it has something to do with the menu not being able to leave the bounds of the window so it's defaulting to the right of the button but unsure what would cause that to happen.

Comment: May I know the differences between the two apps you created? Are they both UWP apps? If you want to display the flyout like Picture1, you could try to [ShowAt()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.menuflyout.showat?view=winrt-19041) method to show the flyout placed at the specified offset, it automatically renders outside the application window if possible and required.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the suggestion. Adding FileFlyout.ShowAt(MainGrid, open); to public MainPage() does allow for the menu flyout to extend ouside of the window. However, when I first open the menu, it opens within the app window as before. On the second click, extends outside of the window. It may have something to do with this mentioned in the documnetation for ShowAt():

"Some properties might not flow as expected, such as FlowDirection. To ensure correct flow, you can set the flow direction in the MenuFlyoutPresenter The MenuFlyoutPresenter must be set before the MenuFlyout is first shown."

Comment: @faywang-MSFT in regard to differences between the apps, the second is a repository I'm modifying so I'm still digging through it but, to my limited knowledge, it seems to have the same Code Behind structure as my original app.

Comment: When I click the DropDownButton and call the ShowAt() method, it can always display ouside of the window. I can't reproduce this issue. Where did you put the ShowAt() method? Can you provide a simple sample that can be reproduced for us to test?